# Stop and Restart function for custom jQuery Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for **a solution to restart and stop a custom jQuery slider.**

I have inserted the custom jQuery slider from here: **http://jsfiddle.net/mjaA3/1662/**

**I have used the slider for three slideshows on the same page.**
Those three slideshows are inside of three buttons, that play a movie when activated and show
the slides inside of the button, while the movie is playing.

I want the slideshow inside those buttons to reset (and stop),
when another of those three buttons is activated.

For now, the slideshow starts inside of a function that is called when the button
is clicked. But it still needs to be reseted, otherwise it stacks up (and still plays).

**This is the shortened code of the fiddle:**

```
    var triggers = window.vorher.find('.fortschrittwrap .note');
    var images = window.vorher.find('.notificationwrap .ce_text');
    var lastElem = triggers.length-1;
    var target;

    triggers.first().addClass('active');
    images.hide().first().show();

    function sliderResponse(target) {
        images.fadeOut(300).eq(target).fadeIn(300);
        triggers.removeClass('active').eq(target).addClass('active');
    }

    triggers.click(function() {
        if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
            target = $(this).index();
            sliderResponse(target);
            resetTiming();
        }
    });



    function sliderTiming() {
        target = window.vorher.find('.fortschrittwrap .note.active').index();
        target === lastElem ? target = 0 : target = target+1;
        sliderResponse(target);
    }

    var timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },5000);
    function resetTiming() {
        clearInterval(timingRun);
        timingRun = setInterval(function() { sliderTiming(); },5000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with clearInterval(timingRun) attached to a clickEvent inside of the function!